# Отображение метки пользователя на карте в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Задача состоит в следующем: нужно отобразить маркер пользователя на карте по введенным им данным(город, улица,дом). Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать это используя интерфейс WPF.

Comment: А как вы собираетесь искать координаты по адресу?

Comment: У Яндекс.Карт кажется есть API. Вам [туда](https://tech.yandex.ru/MAPS/) или [сюда](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/geocoding/about-docpage/).